# Framerate chug every second or so in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, performance

I have a fairly old gaming computer (5 years old or so) that I built, and used to play TF2 just fine.  Starting about a year ago, I started getting a consistent framerate chug/freeze every second or so.  It is super annoying since it happens so consistently.  I do not think this is a hardware issue since I used to be able to run TF2 perfectly at high settings.  I also recently reformatted my hard drive and reinstalled drivers and everything trying to fix this issue, but to no avail.

Anything more I could try?

Comment: Two things. 

1. 5 Years Old tells me it's probably out of date by now.  I used to be able to play TF2 pretty smoothly on my current computer, and recently started experiencing the same choppiness. Valve constantly updates TF2, and any number of new things, from particle effects, to number of players, to server-side plugins, could be reducing your framerate.  2. You say you reinstalled your drivers.  Did you reinstall the proper drivers for the proper hardware, and not just the most recent drivers made by that company?  Could be improper driver install.

Comment: Hardware fails every so often.  Does this chugging and freezing happen with anything else?  If so, it might be a sign your hard drive is going.

Comment: I had this problem years ago with Knights of the Old Republic and maybe 1 or 2 other games. Turns out it was a problem with the wireless network card and my video card together. Removing the card fixed the problem.

Never happened in any other game.

So maybe start pulling out hardware to see if it goes away?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking I am just out of date for everything and its time for a new machine, but I'm not ready to drop the cash for a new rig without trying to fix it.  I have installed the correct drivers for my hardware but I could start over and try again. The harddrive might be an issue as well since my computer is so old.  I've noticed some other slow down while hitting the harddrive.

Comment: You say you reformatted your hard drive, but did you restore TF2 install from an archive, or redownload it proper from Steam? If you havent, do a fresh install of TF2 by deleting local content, then delete the TF2 folder in your steamapps directory

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment above, there are a few things you can try if your framerate is proving to be choppy.

1. Upgrade your graphics card - The surefire way.  Find a more recent graphics card (doesn't have to be top-end, but mid-range at least is preferable) and, after making sure it's compatable with your computer, purchase it and have it installed.
2. Make sure you have the proper driver installed - The most recent driver from the company that made your graphics card is NOT always the right one.  Make sure it matches with your own graphics card.
3. Lower your graphic settings - The easiest thing to do.  Open up TF2, go into options, go into the video tab and click 'advanced'.  You will want to know what type of graphics card you have, and you will want to set most of the options to low (but do a bit of research - some settings when set to low will *reduce* performance).

TF2 is an evolving game, and they have added many things over the years.  So it's entirely possible your five-year old computer is no longer up to snuff for playing the game.  You may need an upgrade, or at the very least to lower your graphic settings for higher performance.

Comment: It's worth noting that most Source games are usually more CPU than GPU intensive. If you have a really crappy GPU than by all means upgrade it, but chances are if you already have a good GPU than your CPU could be causing the bottleneck. I have a somewhat dated CPU, and I run the game fine with [these specs](http://pastebin.com/0HB8ex9L).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this Low FPS fix guide?

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1093560

Summary:

It mentions a stats folder C:\Program Files\Steam\appcache\stats where a file called UserGameStats_0000_0000 (digits may vary) is updated during gameplay.

Virus scanners notice the file changes and often slow down your machine while they are scanning this file (which may get huge).

The solution is to exclude this folder and all files in it from your virus scanner.

Comment: Can you summarize the linked info?  That way, if that thread ever gets removed, or the site is not available, your answer is still valid.  Besides; saves people a click.